# Can the vote retraction window be made longer if you don't have a competing answer?

Tags: feature-request, voting

I have had a number of cases where I have voted on an answer with the best of intentions, and then gone on to read other answers and/or comments and realize that my vote was ill-cast.  However, usually the realization comes too late to retract my vote.

It is really necessary to have such a short window of time to change your vote.  Can it not be 30 minutes or an hour as long as I don't have a competing answer on the question?  I assume the time limit is only to control/limit tactical-voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty simple to do a check against whether you have answered the question or not.  I think this is a very practical idea, that would save frustration for those of us who have reflexes that are a little too quick.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could wait before voting; after all, what's the rush?
You could first read other answers, comments, and finally cast your votes.

This feature is in place to avoid gaming the system, it's working great as it is.

Comment: Sometimes one doesn't realize they have the wrong vote cast until another answer comes up that shows how things went wrong.

Comment: *"The first to plead his case seems right, until another comes and examines him."* -- Proverbs 18:17

Comment: @mmyers: Which is why the US legal system has the defense present their case after the prosecution!

Comment: @Downvoter: No it's not.